# Update table from csv file select first field?

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a series of CSV files that I had wanted to import into MySQL. To first populate the table I did the following;

```
mysql -u root -p apn -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/opt/cell.csv' INTO TABLE data FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';"
```

Where the CSV contents as;

`89xx,31xx,88xx,35xx,ACTIVATED,250.0MB,GPRS,96xx,0,0,2,false,DEFAULT`

The one unique field is the first starting with '89xx' (which goes into column named 'iccid').

Now I want to do is update the table, but clueless how to use the first entry in the CSV to update the rest of the row? It will be like the 4th field that I need to get updated overtime as that is the value that will change (data usage for specific cellular device). I don't have that much of a problem emptying the table before doing a whole new import, I was thinking though it was a better practice to just update, I will eventually need update several times a day.

Since I have no practical skills in any language, or mysql for that matter, would it be best to just insert into a temp table and update from that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> REPLACE

before

> INTO

keyword to update/replace your row.

```
LOCAL INFILE '/opt/cell.csv' REPLACE INTO TABLE data FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';"
```

To ignore your duplicate index you can use

> IGNORE

keyword before

> INTO

[Load data manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)

Comment: WOW, I never thought it would have been that easy, but it worked. I was even afraid after doing a few searches I would need to use Python or something. Thank you